# Call depth overflow in recursive PowerShell function, is there a workaround?

Tags: powershell

I made a script with PowerShell that checks if Internet Explorer is running, and if it isn't, runs a shortcut that starts it in [Kiosk mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interactive_kiosk#Internet_kiosk).
Here's the script:

```
Invoke-Item 'C:\Users\User\Links\iexplorekiosk.lnk'
Function Processchecker {
    $ProcessIE = Get-Process iexplore -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    if (!$ProcessIE) {
        Invoke-Item 'C:\Users\User\Links\iexplorekiosk.lnk'
    }
    Processchecker
}
Processchecker
```

Although when I run this I get a "call depth overflow" error, which I believe means it runs a function in a function and spirals, and I believe the maximum in PowerShell is 10.

Is there a workaround? Because I don't see it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You call `ProcessChecker` out of the `if` block so no matter if the process is found or not, you will recurse one level each time.

An immediate fix would be to add the recursive call to the `if`clause like this:

```
Invoke-Item 'C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe'

Function Processchecker {
    $ProcessIE = Get-Process iexplore -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    if (!$ProcessIE) {
        Invoke-Item 'C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe'

        Processchecker
    }
}

Processchecker
```

> [In this scenario, a `while` loop would suffice and be easier on memory.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19094834/powershell-call-depth-overflow-recursive-function-do-you-have-a-workaround#comment28236989_19094993)

Comment: +1 A key element of recursion is a termination condition otherwise the call recurses until it runs out of stack space or, in the case of PowerShell, hits the recursion limit. Moving the call to Processchecker inside the if statement creates that termination condition - i.e. when $ProcessIE *is* not null the recursion is terminated.  Although, in this scenario, a while loop would suffice and be easier on memory.